# jquery timer shouldn't reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload the page and timer shouldn't be rest on page reload to next part, is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What do you mean by, timer Shouldn't be rest on page reload to next part ?

Comment: i have a timer in jquery , and its been referesh on next part of training

Comment: Impossible to do as the timer has to refresh on each page load. You could try and store the value in a cookie but if the user has cookies disabled then your back to square one.

Comment: Alternatively, don't reload the whole page - and the load the rest of the content in via Ajax

Answer (score 0):

What type of application you're trying to develope?

1) if it's an chrome extension
- you can try localStorage

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API#localStorage

2) if it's a webpage
- you can try cookies or session.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp